# Storing coordinates and characteristics of objects in a 2D grid in an ArrayList

Tags: java, grid, 2d

I have a grid, made as as an Array of Arrays holding 1 character each (char [][]).

On that grid, i built houses, taking up one or multiple blocks of the grid.
I would like to store the location (grid coordinates) and characteristics (price, upkeep) in some sort of list.

The house object is part of an enum containing multiple objects with these characteristics:

```
public enum Building {
    HOUSE(width, height, price, upkeep, symbol)
    FACTORY(width, height, price, upkeep, symbol)
}
```

- width and height are the number of tiles in the grid it takes up
- symbol is the Character that is used in the grid to represent the specific building

I thought to do it this way: (pseudocode)

```
ArrayList<house> buildings = new ArrayList<House>
```

But how could i add the location of the house (the x and y coordinates in this arrayList? Should I use another datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling your enum should be `BuildingType` if your two house objects could have different properties, like what you mentioned location.

Create a `Building` class, which has something like `int x; int y;` and a `BuildingType` (the enum) indicating which kind of the building it is.

If it is necessary you can have super class `Building` and two (or more?) sub types (`House`, `Factory`, `Apartment` etc) In this case you don't need the enum any longer.  All is up to your requirement.

Comment: I've created that class, with int x; int y and the BuildingType. Whata Datatype would you recommend to store the building objects in? Thanks!